# Parsing data elements and it's attributes from dataset into an array

Tags: perl

I have a data set with different types of plans, the data below shows the activeplans and pastplans elements, (and other plans not included in the example).

I think the data can be represented as follows

```
$data->activeplans->activeplanloc[activeplan->{}, activeplan->{},
...activeplan->{}] $data->pastplans->pastplanloc[pastplan->{},
pastplan->{}, ...pastplan->{}]
```

Each plan element has number of attributes, for instance id, lat, long, numpersons (and other attributes not included in the example)

My goal is to loop through all the plan items and extract the attributes.

Also note, the ...planloc[] outer element and the lat/long fields it contains along with the empty ...plan[] - can be ignored.

This is the loop I tried to do it with, but I'm stuck on exacting the activeplan elements, can you help correct my syntax error, I don't now how to properly load the elements into an array given this data stucture?

```
foreach my $planArrayItem (@{$data->{"activeplans"}->{"activeplanloc"}->{"activeplan"}{}}) { 
    #...
    if (exists $planArrayItem->{numpersons}) {
        $tmp .= "<li>Number of personal: $projArrayItem->{numpersons}</li>";
    } 
    #...
}
```

Oh, and this is the data set.

```
{ 'updatetime' => '3/24/2021 11:44:19 AM', 'pastplans' => 
{ 'pastplanloc' => [ { 'longitude' => '-29.51502', 'latitude' =>
 '32.307558', 'pastplan' => { 'planclass' => 'A', 'longitude' =>
 '-29.51502', 'id' => '211', 'latitude' => '32.307558', 
 'numlocations' => '15' } }, { 'longitude' => '-28.798305',
 'latitude' => '32.656135', 'pastplan' => [ { 'id' => '214',
 'longitude' => '-28.798305', 'latitude' => '32.656135',
 'planclass' => 'E', 'numlocations' => '16' }, { 'longitude' => 
 '-28.798305', 'id' => '215', 'latitude' => '32.656135', 'planclass'
 => 'C', 'numlocations' => '21' } ] } ] }, 'activeplans' => 
 { 'activeplanloc' => [ { 'latitude' => '33.132491', 'activeplan'
 => [ { 'planclass' => 'B', 'longitude' => '-25.304968', 'id' =>
 '942', 'latitude' => '33.132491', 'numpersons' => '17' }, 
 { 'numpersons' => '21', 'planclass' => 'G', 'id' => '943',
 'longitude' => '-25.304968', 'latitude' => '33.132491' } ],
 'longitude' => '-25.304968' }, { 'latitude' => '33.097290',
 'activeplan' => { 'numpersons' => '31', 'id' => '944',
 'longitude' => '-25.295086', 'latitude' => '33.097290',
 'planclass' => 'M' }, 'longitude' => '-25.295086' } ] } };
```

This is the XML format if there is a better way to format it while reading in perhaps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plans>
    <updatetime>3/24/2021 11:44:19 AM</updatetime>
    <pastplans>
        <pastplanloc latitude="32.307558" longitude="-29.51502">
            <pastplan planclass="A" id="211" numpersons="15" latitude="32.307558" longitude="-29.51502"/>
        </pastplanloc>
        <pastplanloc latitude="32.656135" longitude="-28.798305">
            <pastplan planclass="E" id="214" numpersons="16" latitude="32.656135" longitude="-28.798305"/>
            <pastplan planclass="C" id="215" numpersons="21" latitude="32.656135" longitude="-28.798305"/>
        </pastplanloc>
    </pastplans>
    <activeplans>
        <activeplanloc latitude="33.132491" longitude="-25.304968">
            <activeplan planclass="B" id="942" numpersons="17" latitude="33.132491" longitude="-25.304968"/>
            <activeplan planclass="G" id="943" numpersons="21" latitude="33.132491" longitude="-25.304968"/>
        </activeplanloc>
        <activeplanloc latitude="33.097290" longitude="-25.295086">
            <activeplan planclass="M" id="944" numpersons="31" latitude="33.097290" longitude="-25.295086"/>
        </activeplanloc>
    </activeplans>
</plans>
```

Comment: The formatting is really bad. Use code formatting for code and data set.

Comment: The "data set" has syntax errors. Please fix it.

Comment: How to you check for syntax errors?

Comment: Copy your `$data = ...` assignment into a file and try to run it with perl...

Comment: That data structure looks like  nightmare. Is there any chance that you can make it sane and save a lot of work later?

Comment: Perhaps, I added in the XML format that the source file was like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your **new** "data set", the correct code is:

```
foreach my $planArrayItem (@{$data->{"activeplans"}->{"activeplanloc"}}) { 
    #...
    my $plans = ref $planArrayItem->{"activeplan"} eq "ARRAY" ? 
        $planArrayItem->{"activeplan"} : [$planArrayItem->{"activeplan"}];
    foreach my $plan (@$plans) {
        if ($plan->{numpersons}) {
            $tmp .= "<li>Number of personal: ".$plan->{numpersons}."</li>";
        } 
    }
}
```

See https://pastebin.com/QeD6ZwZz for a working example

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I will try to scale it up on my real data set now.

Comment: This scaled perfectly - thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I am quite certain that:

```
foreach my $planArrayItem (@{$data->{"activeplans"}->{"activeplanloc"}}) { 
 #...
  if ($planArrayItem->{"activeplan"}{numpersons}) {
     $tmp.= "<li>Number of personal: ".$planArrayItem->{"activeplan"}->{numpersons}."</li>";
  } 
}
```

is the code you are looking for. As you stated above "activeplanloc" contains an array which reference an activeplan. So the outer loop has to iterate over this.

Comment: Hm.. Fixing your $data-assignment, and adding the code runs fine in perl. Here is my testscript. https://pastebin.com/RseJdEaE

Comment: BTW: The XML structure does not correspond to your $data dumpout. You done only have multiple "activeplanloc" entries, but each of them might have multiple "activeplan" entries too. So the code has to contain two foreach loops.

Comment: Your code works, but my data set was wrong, I converted the data above to match the XML, but get a `Not a HASH reference` now when I run it. Could you help? - Thanks